# Windows batch find folder if statement

Tags: windows, automation, batch-file, batch

Assume a file system with the following format

Folder A
--->Folder 1
--->Folder 2
--->Folder 3 etc..
Folder B
--->Folder 4
--->Folder 2
--->Folder 3
Folder C
--->Folder 1
--->Folder 2
--->Folder 3
--->Folder 4

I  need to go one level deep, and only one level deep, and search for 'Folder 1'. If Folder 1 is there, then remove Folder 2 and Folder 3.

I can use a Windows batch file or some other programing language.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working with it?  Can you post any of your example scripts?

Comment: for testing purposes

Comment: for /D /R c:\test %X IN (*.something) DO echo %X > test.txt. How do I match an exact folder name though?

Comment: and it doesn't go only one level deep

Comment: Can you use Powershell?  And will you know the sub-folder names (e.g. Folder 2, Folder 3...) ahead of time? Or do you want to just delete everything under the first level folders if "folder 1" exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script (or line) will check all directories within the current directory one level deep for the presence of `Folder1\NUL`, a well-known ugly trick to distinguish files from directories. Be careful around directories that contain spaces; they may be parsed as two separate locations for `rmdir` to do its damage.

```
for /D %%i in (*) do (
    if exist .\%%i\Folder1\NUL (
        rmdir /S .\%%i\Folder2
        rmdir /S .\%%i\Folder3
    )
)
```

Comment: looks like does every folder in the current directory but not into the folders in that directory? For example in my post above, I need to go into Folder A, B and C and find the folder

Comment: ah nevermind, I see where it goes into the folder now